# Creating site-wide search in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, controller

I'm trying to create a search form that retrieves results based on a user's query for a restaurant's name. So far I've setup its route, controller, and `index` view.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :search, :only => [:index]
```

**search_controller.rb**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @restaurants = Restaurant.search(params[:query])
    else
      @restaurants = Restaurant.all
    end
 end
end
```

**search/index.html.erb**

```
<% @restaurants.each do |restaurant| %>
    <%= restaurant.name %>
<% end %>
```

Here is how the search for is setup:

---

**layouts/_header.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for search_index_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

Right now I'm running into two problems. The first being that if I enter a query and submit, the page doesn't go to the index page. All it does is append the query to the current page I'm on:

```
localhot:3000/restaurant?utf8=✓&query=pizza
```

Second is that I'm getting every restaurant in my db on the index page (as expected). Is there a way that I can make it so the page is blank for anything other than on search requests?

Comment: When you enter `localhost:3000/search` does it hit your `search/index.html.erb` page? How is `localhost:3000/restaurant` related to your question?

Comment: Yes it does. I'll also mention this in my post but if I'm at `localhost:3000/search` and enter my query, it'll fetch results. But if I'm on `localhost:3000/restaurants` or a page other than `/search` I'll get this tacked onto the end of my url instead of it searching: `utf8=✓&query=pizza`

Comment: 1) Did you try with `form_tag` instead of `form_for` 2) In the `else` code path: `@restaurants = []` instead of `@restaurants = Restaurant.all`

Comment: @markets Wow...I feel like I scoured the entire internet and did everything but those two suggestions. Feel feel to post that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

Use `form_tag` instead of `form_for`, since the latter is used to handle specific model objects and this is not the case.

**Question 2**

You can achieve that by:

```
if params[:query].present?
  @restaurants = Restaurant.search(params[:query])
else
  @restaurants = [] # or Restaurant.none if you need a chainable scope
end
```